# Why is this vector copying its first element?

Tags: c++, qt, vector, iterator

I'm relatively new to vectors and this problem has left me baffled.

I have 2 vectors of data which contain a breakdown of a previously analysed graph (locations of peaks, and inflexion points). What the function below is supposed to do is find the inflexion points either side of the mean locations, and store them in "left" and "right" vectors. The left vector gets the correct data, however no matter what I do the right vector collects the first point, and then copies that point every time I try to add a new one.

Code:

```
void pairs(std::vector<int> &means, std::vector<int> &inflexions, std::vector<int> &inflexLeft, std::vector<int> &inflexRight)
{
    //////////////
    //INITIALISE//
    //////////////

    if((means.size() <= 0) || inflexions.size() <= 0)               // If nothing to do
    {
        means.clear();                                              // Leave nothing to chance...
        inflexions.clear();
        return;                                                     // And do nothing =)
    }

    inflexLeft.clear();
    inflexRight.clear();
    inflexLeft.reserve(means.size());
    inflexRight.reserve(means.size());
    std::vector<int>::iterator itI = inflexions.begin();
    std::vector<int>::iterator inflexStart = itI;
    std::vector<int>::iterator endI = inflexions.end();
    std::vector<int>::iterator itM = means.begin();
    std::vector<int>::iterator endM = means.end();

    /////////////////
    //COLLECT PAIRS//
    /////////////////

    for(; (itM != endM) && (itI != endI); itM++, itI++)             // For all the elements in the "means" list
    {
        for(; itI != endI; itI++)
        {
            std::cout<<*itI<<", \t";

            if((*itI) > (*itM))                                     // If we've gone past a mean value...
            {
                if(itI == inflexStart)                              // And this isn't the beginning
                {inflexLeft.push_back(-1);}
                else
                {inflexLeft.push_back(*(itI-1));}                   // Then store the previous inflexion point as LHS inflex for this mean

                inflexRight.push_back(*itI);                        // And store the current inflexion point as the RHS variant
                break;
            }
            else if((itI == endI-1) && (inflexStart != endI-1))     // If we're at the end and have nowhere else to go
            {
                inflexLeft.push_back(*(itI-1));                     // Set the LHS inflex point as the one prior to this...
                inflexRight.push_back(-1);                          // And set the RHS to NULL
                break;
            }
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
1,  2,  3,  4,  11,     
13,     20,     22,     23,     25,     29,     32,     35,     36,     42,     
44,     47,     53,     54,     58,     

Output: (inflexLeft on left, inflexRight on right)
4,      11,     
36,     11,     
54,     11,
```

Every new line in the example above is where a mean occurs and the inflexion points should be stored appropriately. The left hand column of the output is the left inflexion points, and the right should be showing something similar (e.g. 6, 50, 73, ... etc).

I am using QT creator 2.6.1, based on QT 4.8.3 using minGW, on Windows 7 64 bit.
Header files included:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdexcept>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

//////////////////EDIT/////////////////

I've re-doubled my efforts with the debugger. I've used the code below to view the memory address of the point I'm pointing at just before I try to push it back:

```
std::cout << &*itI << ", \t" << *itI << ", \t";
```

From that I've confirmed that the iterator itself isn't magically pointing somewhere else and is indeed iterating. This means that the line of code the problem lies with is:

```
inflexRight.push_back(*itI);                        // And store the current inflexion point as the RHS variant
```

I have already tried putting this line above the LHS push_back operation etc, and the result is the same. I've even tried copying the data into a temporary value before handing it over to inflexRight.push_back with no change in results.

Code to output the final result is in the main function:

```
for(; itLeft != itEnd; itLeft++, itRight++)
{
    std::cout << *itLeft << ", \t" << *itRight << ", \t" << std::endl;
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: Try with smaller input, and step through the code line by line in a debugger.

Comment: Show us smaller output. Attach also some input. Is it all code that prints so much output?

Comment: I've reduced the sample size from 256 to 20, and provided the code in main which displays the received output result from the function.

Comment: What is the output of `inflexLeft` and `inflexRight` right after the two `for` ? I don't see any problem in your `pairs` function so I can't help myself thinking of an output issue. Also, in your edit, `itP` and `itM` don't sound as `inflexLeft` and `inflexRight`.

Comment: I've made it clearer what the outputs of inflexLeft/Right again (forgot to add in the line again after reducing the sample size). itP and itM are recycled names from when I was testing the previous function to get the "M"eans (peaks) and "P"oints of inflexion. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Changed the names of itM and itP to itLeft and itRight to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have run a simplified version with your exact function pairs (the means values are set to output something similar to what you should have I think)

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> inflex = {
            1,  2,  3,  4,  11,
            13, 20, 22, 23, 25, 29, 32, 35, 36, 42,
            44, 47, 53, 54, 58
        },
        means = { 10, 40, 55 },
        left,
        right;

    pairs(means, inflex, left, right);

    std::vector<int>::const_iterator itLeft(left.begin()),
        itRight(right.begin()),
        itEnd(left.end());
    for(; itLeft != itEnd; itLeft++, itRight++)
    {
        std::cout << *itLeft << ", \t" << *itRight << ", \t" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and I got this

```
1,  2,  3,  4,  11,     
13,     20,     22,     23,     25,     29,     32,     35,     36,     42,     
44,     47,     53,     54,     58,     
// Output: (inflexLeft on left, inflexRight on right)
4,      11,     
36,     42,     
54,     58,
```

So I don't think the problem comes from the part of the code you're showing, your `pairs` function should be correct.

Comment: If the function's not the problem  then I'll look elsewhere for problems. Thanks for the double check. If there are no other solutions that work soon then I'll set this as the answer. Thanks again.